# Proof about holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove that if $\Omega$ is convex, $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $\text{Re}(f')>0 $ then $f$ is injection.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have problem with understanding why the last integral doesnt vanish. Can you help me?

Comment: But that is explained in the comments... Since $\text{Re}f'>0$, the real part of the last integral is positive as well, so this integral cannot vanish.

Comment: Oh i get it now, thank you